# WPF Выбор лучшего элемента для хранения данных

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, listbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужен элемент, который выглядит как DataGrid (А может именно он мне и нужен?), у которого есть 3 колонки: id - автоматическая генерация при добавлении строчки, а текст 2-ой и 3-ей колонки должны формироваться из текста, введенного в первый и второй текстблок (по сути я хочу реализовать 2 массива - один для первой колонки и первого текстблока, второй для второй колонки и второго текстблока и собственно привязать к первой колонке первый массив, а ко второй колонке 2 массив).

Что мне для этого лучше (удобнее для реализации через 2 массива и биндинга их к колонкам) использовать? ListBox, ListView, DataGrid? Или что-то другое?

Comment: Нет. Массив должен быть один - и он содержать должен вьюмодели с полями  Id, Column1, Column2 (образно). Ну а далее можно его биндить хоть на DataGrid/ListView(GridView0, хоть на ListBox, хотя если нужно чтобы выглядело как DataGrid, то его можно и взять в первую очередь. А потом поменять при нужде

Comment: @vitidev, почему именно вьюмодели?

Comment: То, что вы хотите, это 3 разных, совершенно не связанных друг с другом списка, а если это совершенно не связанные друг с другом списки, то и делайте 3 рядом стоящих `listBox` или что вам там надо, с добавлением в каждый своих данных.

Comment: Ну так то это просто классы. Но поскольку они тесно связаны с UI и обязаны реализовывать INotifyPropertyChanged, то такие классы обычно вьюмодели. Конечно никто не запрещает реализовать INotifyPropertyChanged  в моделях, но зачем их засорять.